# Angularjs 1.7.7 + webpack - only prod build shows injector module error. How to fix it?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, build

I am working on moving to webpack for my angularjs (1.7.7) app.

webpack.config.js -

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"); // Require  html-webpack-plugin plugin
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/app/index.js'
  }, // __dirname + "/src/app/index.js", // webpack entry point. Module to start building dependency graph
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Folder to store generated bundle
    filename: "bundle.js", // Name of generated bundle after build
    publicPath: "/" // public URL of the output directory when referenced in a browser
  },
  module: {
    // where we defined file patterns and their loaders
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.html/, loader: "raw-loader" },
      { test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/, use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']},
      { test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Array of plugins to apply to build chunk
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + "/src/public/index.html",
      inject: "body"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "style.css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      THREE: 'three',
      'THREE': 'three',
      UIkit: 'uikit',
      'UIkit': 'uikit'
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([{ // Copy the images folder
      from: 'src/public/images/',
      to: 'images/'
    },
    { // copy the html templates
      from: 'src/app/templates/',
      to: 'templates/'
    }]),
    new ImageminPlugin({ test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i }) // optimize all the images
  ],
  devServer: {
    // configuration for webpack-dev-server
    contentBase: "./src/public", //source of static assets
    port: 7600 // port to run dev-server
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true // set to true if you want JS source maps
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ],
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  }
};
```

index.js -

```
    /**
 * Application stating point.
 */
const angular = require("angular");

let app = angular.module("app", [require('angular-touch'), require('angular-route')]);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
  template: require("./templates/home.html")
})
.when("/contact", {
  template: require("./templates/contact.html")
})
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: "/"
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

// app.controller.....
```

Now, this works perfectly fine with webpack-dev-server in dev mode. But when I build it and run the app from the dist folder, it gives the following error.
Since this is minified, I am only guessing that it is the ngRoute that it is not injecting. I have run the webpack command for prod mode with the '--verbose' and there is no angular-route mentioned anywhere.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: t
>
> https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20t%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.7%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dt%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A836%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A24010%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A25600)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20o%20(http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A25905)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A25993)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20t%20(http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A25390)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A25012%0A%20%20%20%20at%20vt%20(http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A1557)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A24871)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ze%20(http%3A%2F%2Fsyntech-009%3A8000%2F1.bundle.js%3A50%3A24207)
>       at 1.bundle.js:50
>       at 1.bundle.js:50
>       at vt (1.bundle.js:50)
>       at m (1.bundle.js:50)
>       at Ze (1.bundle.js:50)
>       at e (1.bundle.js:50)
>       at nt (1.bundle.js:50)
>       at et (1.bundle.js:50)
>       at HTMLDocument. (1.bundle.js:50)
>       at t (1.bundle.js:39)

So far I have tried including the route and touch using require, es6 import syntax and the one shown here. All syntaxes work in dev mode but build doesn't inject it right. I am thinking that I am missing something in the webpack. Any pointers?

Update - since posting this, also tried adding ng-strict-di directive. Even this doesn't make the error show up in dev mode and the prod mode error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function($routeProvider) {}
```

will be minified to ~

```
function(a) {}
```

So you need one of:

1. use full notation `['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {}]`
2. use full notation with `$inject = ['$routeProvider']`
3. use some angularjs-annotate plugin

Comment: Thanks @petr-averyanov. I should have responded earlier. The first one worked for me. I had made the changes for module and controller, but totally missed for the config. As it turns out, this explicit injection needs to be done for all things when minifying - module, controller, config, directive, and whatnot. Hope this will help some others too.

Comment: @Petr Averyanov I have same problem but my project is too large so changing at every place like ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {}] is not possible and a regression may occurs.   Could you please suggest me any alternate solution.

Comment: @AnkitPandey see my answer below.